# Is it possible to have folders under the Opportunity / Notes & Files tab?

Tags: files, contentdocumentlink, fileupload, document, folder

I tried to find out if it's possible to create folders where files can be stored, but all I can find is having the "File" tab separate and accessing the folders there through Libraries.

Once we have an Opportunity, there are multiple types of files we add into Salesforce Lightning, under the tab Notes & Files in the Opportunity itself. As this piles up all files we have for the opportunity in question all together , it creates a mess and it's hard to find the exact type of information needed. Therefore, we want to make use of folders where the different types of documents can be stored.

As I am new to SalesForce, I am trying to find out how to create folders and the only answer I find is how to create a folder in the separate object called Files and then create the folder in Libraries.

Is it possible to have folders set up in a way that when you are in the opportunity, you can view the folders and upload the files in the relevant folder? If so, how is that done?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-productivity/work-with-notes-and-files, it walks through this.

Comment: In this link I couldn't find anything about creating folders visible in the Files related list , which is connected to the record. Is this even an option?

Comment: _Access libraries and the files in libraries (2). Libraries are a way to organize content and share content with colleagues. You can even create folders within libraries, to better organize your content._  . Attach to record: _The Files related list also opens the door to all of the files in Salesforce Files that you have access to, including files in libraries_ .

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps. . . I found your post when I was searching for something for folders on a record as well - but I found this on the appexchange and it's free. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4caiEAB

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199723)